# error: cannot convert `void (*)()' to `float'

Tags: c++, function, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I have a problem converting `void (*)()` to `float`. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void instructions();
void numDays();
void med();
void sur();
void lab();
float room(int days);
float misc(float meds, float surgical, float lab);
float total(float room, float misc);

int main()
{
  int days;
  float meds;
  float surgical;
  instructions();
  numDays();
  med();
  sur();
  lab();
  room( days);
  misc(meds, surgical, lab);
  total( room, misc);
}

void instructions()
{
  cout<<"this program will ask you some questions. After that it will print out all of the users charges and the tital\
 amount that is owed. "<<endl;
}

void numDays()
{
  float days;
  cout<<"Enter in users length of stay. "<<endl;
  cin>> days;
}

void med()
{
  float meds;
  cout<<"Enter int the users medication charges. "<<endl;
  cin>> meds;
}

void sur()
{
  float surgical;
  cout<<"Enter in the users surgical charges. "<<endl;
  cin>> surgical;
}

void lab()
{
  float lab;
  cout<<"Enter in the users lab fees. "<<endl;
  cin>> lab;
}

float room(float days)
{
  float room;

 room = (days*450);

}

float misc(float meds, float surgical, float lab)
{
  float misc;
  misc = (meds + surgical + lab);
  return 0;
}

float total(float room, float misc)
{
 float total;
 total = (room + misc);
  return total;
}
```

These are the error messages I keep getting:

```
:24: error: cannot convert 'void (*)()' to 'float' for argument `3' to `float misc(float, float, float)'
:25: error: cannot convert 'float (*)(int)' to 'float' for argument `1' to `float total(float, float)'
```

Comment: You're passing a function to something expecting a float. That's no more than what the compiler's told you.

Comment: Using better variable and function names - and avoiding overloaded usages of such! - would make this error more obvious.

Answer (score 3):

For example in this statement

```
misc(meds, surgical, lab);
```

argument lab is a function pointer. I did not look through your code but maybe you meant

```
misc(meds, surgical, lab());
```

However even in this case you will get an error because function lab has return type void.
It seems you do not understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

1. In your `room()` function I assume you forgot return statement.
2. `total(room, misc);` - so, here I suppose you expect to have a result of your `room` and `misc` functions. This will work if you do

   ```
   float misc = misc(meds, surgical, lab);
   float room = room(days);
   float total = total(room, misc);
   ```
3. The void functions you have are not doing what you expect. You create *local* variables inside these functions and they are not the same as variables you have in `main`. You can make those functions to return the entered result and then do `float lab = lab()`.
4. Your `misc` function always returns 0 - I believe this is not what you expect.
5. In general, if you have function returning something assign it to a variable, like shown in 2. - otherwise it will not do anything useful and you won't be able to reuse it.

Comment: Oh, I see what was meant .. I was focused on the error in the title too much :|

Answer (score 2):

Ok, let’s start at the beginning. A computer program like your example consists of two different things:

1. Functions: they are active, they *do* something when they are called.
2. Variables: they are passive, they *cannot do* something themselves.

In your program you have two different things (one variable, and one function), and both of them are called `med`. This will lead to confusion. A typical style guide therefore recommends that function names have a verb in their name, for example `read_med`, so you know what the function is supposed to do. On the other hand, variable names are often nouns, such as `med`, `days`, `total`.

The function then looks like this:

```
float read_med() { // this is a function (active part)
  float med; // and this is a variable (passive part)
  cout << "Enter the medication amount: ";
  cin >> med;
  return med;
}
```

You can then call this function like this:

```
float med = read_med(); // the round parentheses mean “call the function, run the code”
float days = read_days();

float total = med * days;
cout << "Total: " << total << endl;
```